# Markdown YAML date settings using functions that require library()

Tags: r, date, yaml, r-markdown

I'd like to set date in YAML in R Markdown settings using following function:

```
paste(month(previous_month(part="start"),label=TRUE,locale=Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English"),abbr=FALSE), year(previous_month(part="start")), sep=" ")
```

but this code contains functions from 2 packages: *timeperiodsR* and *lubridate*, so it's necessary to prior use library(timeperiodsR) and library(lubridate).

How should code after `date:` look like, because the following is not working?

```
title: " "
date: '`r library(timeperiodsR) library(lubridate) paste(month(previous_month(part="start"),label=TRUE,locale=Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English"),abbr=FALSE), year(previous_month(part="start")), sep=" ")`'
output: 
   html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 2
    toc_float:
      collapsed: false
      smooth_scroll: false
fig_align: 'center'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `";"` to indicate *newline*:

```
---
title: "mytitle"
date: '`r library(timeperiodsR); library(lubridate); paste(month(previous_month(part="start"),label=TRUE,locale=Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English"),abbr=FALSE), year(previous_month(part="start")), sep=" ")`'
output: 
   html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 2
    toc_float:
      collapsed: false
      smooth_scroll: false
fig_align: 'center'
---
```

Or use *base* (no dependencies, one-liner):

```
---
title: "mytitle"
date: '`r format(seq(Sys.Date(), length = 2, by = "-1 months")[ 2 ], format = "%B %Y")`'
output: 
   html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 2
    toc_float:
      collapsed: false
      smooth_scroll: false
fig_align: 'center'
---
```

Both give the below same output:

[image]